# using jQuery UI datepicker in DotNetNuke instead Telerik RadCalendar

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui, datepicker, dotnetnuke

How Can I Substitute jQueryUI Datepicker With Telerik RadCalendar (default) in DotNetNuke 6+ for all mores including the core?

Telerik RadCalendar does'nt support my date format.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The process for this is really simple.  Just use a regular textbox and do.

```
$("#<%= txtMyControl.ClientID %>").datepicker();
```

And you will be set to go!

You might need to request the registration of jQuery UI in the codebehind as well.

Comment: Hi Mitchel
I supposed to substitute it in core of DotNetNuke ... Is there anyway to replace dnnDatepicker with another controller in a way to substitute RadDatePicker with jQueryUI in all modules?

Comment: Not without extensive core modifications.

Comment: Excuse Me Mitchel Sellers, But is there a tutorial about this in the web? Thanks

Comment: No, there isn't really as it is commonly recommended to not modify the core due to the fact that you will not be able to upgrade.

Answer (score 3):

DotNetNuke provides with inbuilt jquery.js and jquery-ui.js
so you don't have to bother to link them separately

If you are developing a custom DNN module add this to your user control view.ascx file.

I have txtStartDate as a text field on the form where I wanted my calander to be rendered on click.

To achieve this I added this code at the top of my ascx page after the standard includes.

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(function () {
    $("#<%= txtStartDate.ClientID %>").datepicker();
});
</script>
```

The calender takes the size based on your text size if it is appearing bigger that your expectation

set it style like this

```
<style>
div.ui-datepicker{
font-size:10px;
}
</style>
```